# Jquery: How to show date with textbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am newbie in jquery and i wrote below code

```
<h1>Type your comment below </h1>
<h2>TextBox value : <label id="msg"></label>-<label id="date"></label></h2>
<div style="padding:16px;">
    TextBox : <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Type Your Comment"></input>
</div>
<button id="Get">Get TextBox Value</button>
```

```js
var fullDate = new Date();
$("button").click(function(){
    $('#msg').html($('input:text').val());        
});
```

How to display the Date when submit button press for the label have  `id="date"`?
When user press submit button i want to display

```
"User entered Textbox Value - Date with time"
```

Comment: Which date you want to show?

Comment: like this? `$('#date').html($('input:text').val());`

Comment: I want to show input value then - Current Date when submit button press something like `My Comment 1- 06/28/2016 time`

Comment: Use `$('#date').html(new Date().toString()` to put the date there, and take a look at http://momentjs.com/ for further handling dates in JS

Comment: @NikhilGirraj Thanks this is what i am looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use proper css selectors to add the messages and date. Refer code below :

```
 $("button").click(function() {
    var msg = $('input:text').val();
    var fullDate = new Date();

    $('#msg').html(msg);
    $('#date').html(toLocal(fullDate));
  });

 function toJSONLocal (date) {
   var local = new Date(date);
   local.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
   return local.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
 }

 function toLocal (date) {
   var local = new Date(date);
   local.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
   return local.toJSON().replace('T', ' ').slice(0, 19);
 }
```

Note: toJSONLocal, toLocal is used to format date.

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/q8zmLebz/

Answer (score 0):

Just use this :

```
var fullDate = new Date();
$('#date').text(fullDate);
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Get").click(function() {
    var fullDate = new Date();
    $('#date').text(fullDate);
    $('#msg').text($('#comment').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Type your comment below </h1>

<h2>TextBox value : <label id="msg"></label>-<label id="date"></label></h2>

<div style="padding:16px;">
  TextBox :
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Type Your Comment" id="comment" />
</div>

<button id="Get">Get TextBox Value</button>
```